# error in clojure for calling java factory method: more than one matching method found

Tags: clojure

In this example - http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/package-summary.html, when I try to run in clojure, I get an error.

```
(import 'javax.measure.unit.SI)
(import 'javax.measure.Measure)

(Measure/valueOf 2 SI/KILOGRAM)
;; => More than one matching method found: valueOf
[Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

Is there anyway around this?

### update

the actual java code is this:

```
public static <Q extends Quantity> Measure<java.lang.Integer, Q> valueOf(
        int intValue, Unit<Q> unit) {
    return new Integer<Q>(intValue, unit);
}

public static <Q extends Quantity> Measure<java.lang.Float, Q> valueOf(
        float floatValue, Unit<Q> unit) {
    return new Float<Q>(floatValue, unit);
}
```

the error I get is:

```
More than one matching method found: valueOf
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]

Restarts:
 0: [QUIT] Quit to the SLIME top level

Backtrace:
  0:          Compiler.java:2360 clojure.lang.Compiler.getMatchingParams
  1:          Compiler.java:1555 clojure.lang.Compiler$StaticMethodExpr.
  2:           Compiler.java:938 clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse
  3:          Compiler.java:6455 clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq
  4:          Compiler.java:6262 clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze
  5:          Compiler.java:6223 clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze
  6:          Compiler.java:5618 clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse
  7:          Compiler.java:5054 clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse
  8:          Compiler.java:3674 clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse
  9:          Compiler.java:6453 clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq
```

Comment: On a terminology note, `Measure/valueOf` is actually a _factory method_ rather than a _constructor_. Constructors are called using the `new` keyword in Java, whereas `valueOf` is a normal static method that returns an instance of `Measure`.

Comment: Thanks, it's Changed to factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few basic casting examples:

```
(import 'javax.measure.unit.SI)
(import 'javax.measure.Measure)

; Integer Value
; will call: 
;  public static <Q extends Quantity> Measure<java.lang.Integer, Q> valueOf
(Measure/valueOf (Integer. 2) SI/KILOGRAM)

; Long  value 
; will call: 
;  public static <Q extends Quantity> Measure<java.lang.Long, Q> valueOf
(Measure/valueOf (cast Long 2) SI/KILOGRAM)

; Float value
; will call: 
;  public static <Q extends Quantity> Measure<java.lang.Float, Q> valueOf
(Measure/valueOf (Float. 2.0) SI/KILOGRAM)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you're invoking a static overloaded method (i.e `Measure.valueOf(double, Unit)` vs `Measure.valueOf(float, Unit)`). Try casting your value to the desired type like so (assuming you want to invoke `Measure/valueOf(float, Unit)`:

```
(Measure/valueOf (float 2) SI/KILOGRAM)
```

Comment: Sorry, i can't see any updates on your question. Could you post the error you get?

Comment: sorry... i was editing it just then =) i've put up the error as well

Comment: you can try it yourself... include `[clj-science/jscience "4.3.1"]` in your dependencies and do what I did.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried it out and this works:

```
(Measure/valueOf (Integer. 2) SI/KILOGRAM)
```

As does this:

```
(Measure/valueOf (cast Long 2) SI/KILOGRAM)
```

Comment: Trust me to type (long 1),(float 1) and (int 1)

Comment: Yeah, those don't do the same thing.